# How to write a script to automate the process of manually adding services.DbContext to startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Every time a new database is added, a new contextdb is generated. The contextdb naming is different, and there is a need to place it into startup.cs automatically without developer to manually insert it every time.

At the end of the day there will be

```
Services.adddbcontext<mydbcontext>(.......);
Services.adddbcontext<testindgdb>(.......);
Services.adddbcontext<compandsayaDB>(.......);
Services.adddbcontext<aq2d23db>(.......);
```

How do i automate this process? A script? Or?

Comment: You have to give use more explanation. Are you trying to midify a cs file when creating a new database ?

Comment: If your app need different databases, than you just add them manually, that's ok. If you want to switch between environments, e.g. for testing, you should configure your DB in appsettings. Testing is not a different DbContext, it's the same context in a different physical DB.